# useEffect calling function even if input is not changed

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, settimeout

Home.js

```
export default function Home({ movies }) {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [inputChanged, setInputChanged] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const useDelayFuctionRef = useRef(null);
  const router = useRouter();
  const client = {id:'',pass:''}
  useEffect(() => {
    const searchQuery = () => {
      router.push(`${router.pathname}/?search=${searchTerm}`);
    };
    if (inputChanged) {
      useDelayFuctionRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        searchQuery();
        setInputChanged(false);
        setLoading(false);
      }, 2000);
    }
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(useDelayFuctionRef.current);
      console.log("cleaned");
    };
  }, [searchTerm]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
              setInputChanged(true);
              setLoading(true);
            }}
          />
      </div>
      <div>
        {movies.map((movie) => {
          return (
            <MovieBlock key={movie._id} movie={movie} client={client}/>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
  const movies = await fetch(query.string);
  return {
    props: {
      movies,
    },
  };
}
```

MovieBlock.js

```
export default function MovieBlock({ movie, client }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link
        key={movie._id}
        href={`/movie/${movie.slug}`}
      >
        <img src={movie.vertical_image} />
      </Link>
      <div>
        <span>
          {movie.genre.map((genre) => <Link key={genre._id} href={`/genre/${genre.slug}`}>{genre.title}</Link>
          }
        </span>
        <span>{movie.title}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click on any `<Link>` in `MovieBlock.js` it waits for 2 seconds, and then redirects to the page link that was clicked, the `return` function from `useEffect` logs "cleaned" after redirecting to the desired page, why is this happening on redirects other than `input:onChange` although having condition ? Is there something to do with cleanup function ?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are experiencing with the `useEffect` cleanup function is related to how React handles component unmounting and updating.

In your `Home` component, you have a `useEffect` hook with a dependency array containing `[searchTerm]`. This means that the effect will run whenever `searchTerm` changes. When you click on a `<Link>` in the `MovieBlock.js` component, it navigates to a different page, causing the `Home` component to unmount and then remount when the new page loads. This unmounting and remounting causes the `useEffect` cleanup function to run before the component is unmounted.

Here's what happens during the process:

1. You type in the input, which changes the `searchTerm` state, triggering the `useEffect` with a 2-second delay.
2. Before the 2-second delay elapses, you click on a `<Link>`, which triggers the navigation to a different page.
3. The current `Home` component unmounts since you are moving to a new page, and the `useEffect` cleanup function is called, which clears the timeout using `clearTimeout(useDelayFuctionRef.current);` and logs "cleaned".
4. The new page loads, and the `Home` component is re-rendered, but this time with a new state and props.
5. Since the component is re-rendered, the `useEffect` with the 2-second delay is set up again, and the process repeats for any further changes to `searchTerm`.

To avoid this behavior, you can add a dependency to your `useEffect` hook, so it only runs when the component is initially mounted. By providing an empty dependency array (`[]`), the effect will only run once, equivalent to the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method in class components.

Here's the updated `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const searchQuery = () => {
    router.push(`${router.pathname}/?search=${searchTerm}`);
  };
  if (inputChanged) {
    useDelayFuctionRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
      searchQuery();
      setInputChanged(false);
      setLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  }
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(useDelayFuctionRef.current);
    console.log("cleaned");
  };
}, [searchTerm, inputChanged]); // Add inputChanged as a dependency
```

By including `inputChanged` as a dependency, the `useEffect` will also run when `inputChanged` changes, but since it is a state that is managed within the component, it won't be affected by the unmounting behavior during navigation.

Comment: It still does load 2 seconds before redirecting, even without touching the input box

Comment: you can test if the input has changed before calling the useEffect by putting the useEffect inside an ifelse

Comment: I tried to log `inputChanged` but it shows `false`